# My Captcha is not appearing in html form

Tags: html

Well I got this code

```html
<html>
<div class="form">
     <h2>Login to your account</h2>
     <form action="#" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required=" ">
       <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required=" ">
       <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="thecode"></div>
       <input type="submit" value="Login">
     </form>
      </div>
      <div class="form">
     <h2>Create an account</h2>
     <form action="#" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required=" ">
       <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required=" ">
       <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" required=" ">
       <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required=" ">
       <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="thecode"></div>
       <input type="submit" value="Register">
     </form>
      </div>
          </html>
```

However it doesn't load in the form like i didn't add the captcha code .. any solutions ?

Comment: you are trying to insert some image or using particular library.

Comment: Are you actually loading the recaptcha JavaScript file?

Comment: have you include the api.js ? and other related configs ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you provide more info?Did you add recaptcha sdk in head section?And do you use correct keys?Also check if you correctly add domain in Domains list.